# Catching bad url when using ConcatenatingAudioSource in just_audio

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio

I got a playlist of AudioSources that contains some bad url one (return 400 error with some info). And I use ConcatenatingAudioSource to wrap those audios and pass to setAudioSource. 
When player play that bad url audio sources, it throw something like:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:624)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:596)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:389)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1014)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:409)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(10255):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/AudioPlayer(10255): TYPE_SOURCE: Response code: 400
```

How can I catch the error in this situation?

What I've tried to catch so far:

```
    audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen(
      (event) {},
      onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        print('A stream error occurred: $e');
      },
    );

    audioPlayer.sequenceStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A sequence error occurred: $e');
    });
    audioPlayer.sequenceStateStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A sequencestate error occurred: $e');
    });
    audioPlayer.processingStateStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A processingState error occurred: $e');
    });
    audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A playerStateStream error occurred: $e');
    });
    audioPlayer.playingStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A playingStream error occurred: $e');
    });
    audioPlayer.bufferedPositionStream.listen((event) {},
        onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A bufferedPositionStream error occurred: $e');
    });

    try {
      await audioPlayer
         .setAudioSource(_playlist, preload: true)
         .onError((e, stackTrace) {
             print('A player error occurred: $e');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading playlist occurred: $e");
    }
```

Comment: That first listen/onError should work because that's what the official example does, which works. Maybe you should testing the official example, modifying it with your URL to see if it reports the stream error and if it fails to, you can report that as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try playback and catch the error like this:

```
    try {
        // Playback
    } on Exception catch (_) {
        // Error handling
    }
```

Comment: I hoped this could be this easy but it didn't. I tried following catches but not worked.
`audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen(
      (event) {},
      onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        print('A stream error occurred: $e');
      },
    );
// try other streams too
    try {
      await audioPlayer
          .setAudioSource(_playlist, preload: true)
          .onError((e, stackTrace) {
        print('A player error occurred: $e');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading playlist occurred: $e");
    }`

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried to your question, with a normal layout so it becomes readable? It is not readable like in the comment.